# /proc filesystem advantages

Tags: linux, filesystems, virtual

I came across this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-proc.html

When I researched more on `/proc` filesystem, I came to know that its main advantage to be that it is residing in the kernel space. But still a user space program is able to write to it if it has appropriate permissions. I really don't understand whats going on. Could anyone explain!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see /proc as a pipe to kernel. You can modify kernel parameters and see what kernel is doing at a moment in time.

Regards

Comment: Do you mean to say that /proc is a named pipe?

Answer (score 1):

In linux a filesystem is implemented via a series of system calls that provide all the operations you expect, `open`, `close`, `read`, `write`, that kind of thing.

The kernel provides a method of mapping these calls to an underlying filesystem implementation. This mapping layer is called the VFS and there are a bunch of pages that describe it (for example [the VFS Tour](http://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/fs/vfstour.html)).

Not all filesystems necessarily live on a spinning disk or any permanent storage medium. As you said, /proc is completely in memory. The implementation of its functions like `read` and `write` provide access to various aspects of the Linux kernel.

Comment: Ok.. here is some  observation -- I echoed to /proc/filename but I got permission denied error ( I was root when I echoed) but when I run a c program that opens a file and writes to it, it the value gets written to the /proc. I am clueless about whats happening here!

Comment: Did you do something like "sudo echo blah > /proc/filename"? In that case only the "echo blah" part is running as root, not the output redirection.

Comment: Oh..!! Wonderful!! But then I opened the file with 666 which means anyone could write to it rite? And even then the problem persists!

Comment: Which file is this by the way? Only some proc files can be written to, others are read-only no matter what the permissions are. In general you shouldn't be writing to /proc and expecting normal things to happen. It is not a general storage space. :)

Comment: I am aware that its not a genereal storage space... I created an lkm which I used to open a file called /proc/filename with 666 as permission bits..